# gradlew connectedAndroidTestFails on createDebugCoverageReport

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, jacoco, gradlew

When I run .gradlew createCoverageReport I get the following error:

```
:WFMRecipeApplication:connectedAndroidTest
Tests on Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.VerifyError'
11:36:00 E/Device: Error during Sync: Remote object doesn't exist!
null
java.io.IOException: Failed to pull /data/data/com.project.recipes/coverage.ec from device
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.pullFile(ConnectedDevice.java:115)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:158)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!
    at com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.pullFile(SyncService.java:314)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.pullFile(Device.java:873)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.pullFile(ConnectedDevice.java:108)
    ... 10 more
:WFMRecipeApplication:connectedAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':WFMRecipeApplication:connectedAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/elidd1//connected/index.html
```

But when I access that index.html it looks like this:
[image]

I don't understand why its crashing.. the build gets to about 98% before this fail.  I have a nexus 5 connected running 4.4..

my build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.7.2'
        testApplicationId "------.recipes.application.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('../keystore/WFM_debug.jks')
            storePassword 'wfmrecipes'
            keyAlias 'WFMRecipes'
            keyPassword 'wfmrecipes'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('../keystore/WFM_release.jks')
            storePassword 'wfmrecipes'
            keyAlias 'WFMRecipes'
            keyPassword 'wfmrecipes'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            zipAlign true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            resValue "bool", "isCrittercismEnabled", "true"
            resValue "bool", "isHockeyEnabled", "true"
            testCoverageEnabled true

        }
        debug {
            runProguard false
            zipAlign true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            resValue "bool", "isCrittercismEnabled", "false"
            resValue "bool", "isHockeyEnabled", "false"
            testCoverageEnabled true

        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/drawable', 'src/main/res/menu'] }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
        reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
    }


}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':Project')
    compile project(':WFMStore')
}


buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/comnewrelic-1153' }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/comnewrelic-1154' }
    }
    dependencies {
    }
}
//apply plugin: 'newrelic'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/comnewrelic-1153' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:+'
}

// added to cut down on the number of methods for codecoverage (limit is 65,536 and playservices hogs most of this) - elidd1
def toCamelCase(String string) {
    String result = ""
    string.findAll("[^\\W]+") { String word ->
        result += word.capitalize()
    }
    return result
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    Configuration runtimeConfiguration = project.configurations.getByName('compile')
    ResolutionResult resolution = runtimeConfiguration.incoming.resolutionResult
    // Forces resolve of configuration
    ModuleVersionIdentifier module = resolution.getAllComponents().find { it.moduleVersion.name.equals("play-services") }.moduleVersion

    String prepareTaskName = "prepare${toCamelCase("${module.group} ${module.name} ${module.version}")}Library"
    File playServiceRootFolder = project.tasks.find { it.name.equals(prepareTaskName) }.explodedDir

    Task stripPlayServices = project.tasks.create(name: 'stripPlayServices', group: "Strip") {
        inputs.files new File(playServiceRootFolder, "classes.jar")
        outputs.dir playServiceRootFolder
        description 'Strip useless packages from Google Play Services library to avoid reaching dex limit'

        doLast {
            copy {
                from(file(new File(playServiceRootFolder, "classes.jar")))
                into(file(playServiceRootFolder))
                rename { fileName ->
                    fileName = "classes_orig.jar"
                }
            }
            tasks.create(name: "stripPlayServices" + module.version, type: Jar) {
                destinationDir = playServiceRootFolder
                archiveName = "classes.jar"
                from(zipTree(new File(playServiceRootFolder, "classes_orig.jar"))) {
                    exclude "com/google/ads/**"
                    exclude "com/google/android/gms/analytics/**"
                    exclude "com/google/android/gms/games/**"
                    exclude "com/google/android/gms/plus/**"
                    exclude "com/google/android/gms/drive/**"
                    exclude "com/google/android/gms/ads/**"
                }
            }.execute()
            delete file(new File(playServiceRootFolder, "classes_orig.jar"))
        }
    }

    project.tasks.findAll { it.name.startsWith('prepare') && it.name.endsWith('Dependencies') }.each { Task task ->
        task.dependsOn stripPlayServices
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The apply plug-in part causes the tests to not run.
Like Bill suggested gradle's latest release has jacoco packaged within so it needn't be applied anymore.

My tests recently broke because of this.
Removing that line fixed my issue and I get my reports again.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things.

1. To fix your first error "Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.VerifyError'", upgrade your build tools to 21+. This is a bug in the android build tools that they have fixed. Hooray!
2. You don't have to apply the jacoco plugin, it is part of the android gradle plugin. All you need is 'testCoverageEnabled true' and it will create your .ec file. Applying the plugin doesn't hurt as far as I know, but it's helpful to get your mind around the fact that jacoco is in there already.

The override for 'reportsDir' might not work, so you should also look for your report in 'build/outputs/reports/coverage/debug/index.html'.